# Setup local domain with IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to setup local domains like sub1.mydomain.dev and www.mydomain.dev on my local IIS on Windows 7 to test cross-domain things (asp.net app)... is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be done in IIS, but in the DNS server.

You can spoof this by updating your [hosts](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/edit-hosts-file-in-windows-7-windows-vista/) file and add entries for the additional domain names, pointing them to the same server.

Comment: do i have to install a DNS server on Windows 7 ?

Comment: Windows 7 does not come with its own DNS server.